# How do I pass a variable in a liquibase SQL command?

Tags: postgresql, docker, liquibase, confluence

I am trying to execute a simple sql(posgresql DB) command using liquibase before starting a docker.
Here is my liquibase script "email-reset.xml" which does not work hwn i use the variable (hard coded value works)

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                                       http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
                                       http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext
                                       http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
    <changeSet id="email-reset" author="keanu">
        <comment>Update User Emails in Dev</comment>
        <sql>
            update cwd_user set email_address='${email.reset}';
        </sql>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I have a liquibase.properties file where I defined

```
parameter.email.reset=${OVERWRITE_USER_EMAIL}
```

In the docker file I write

```
ENV OVERWRITE_USER_EMAIL false
```

I want the email in the database to be overwritten when a value is specified in my docker file.

```
OVERWRITE_USER_EMAIL=user@example.com
```

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

If understand your question correctly,

1. Using the [changelog parameters](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html) you can pass value to the Liquibase update process.
2. With the [changeLogPropertyDefined precondition](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html#changelogpropertydefined) one can check if a change log parameter is defined.
3. Instead of plain SQL if you use the [update change](https://b-gyula.github.io/liquibase-doc/documentation/changes/update.html) where you can pass the parameter value in the `value` attribute of the column

```
<changeSet id="email-reset" author="keanu">
   <update>
      <column name='email_address' value='${email.reset}'/>
   </update >
</changeSet>
```

I hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not be adding the `parameter` prefix in your property name. Just specify `email.reset=some_actual_value`.

Second, you cannot have the 'double indirection' that you are using in your example, where you specify an environment variable value in the properties file. There is nothing in the system to perform that replacement.

If you want to have something in your dockerfile that controls the value of email.reset, it would be better to not use the properties file and instead pass the property as a system property on the command line, so that the liquibase run command looks something like this:

```
./liquibase -Demail.reset=true update
```

If the value of email.reset is hard-coded into the dockerfile anyway, there is no need to set the environment variable just to use it in a single place.

Finally, using Liquibase for what is essentially system admin tasks is probably not the best way to approach this task. It would be better if there was something in the application itself that could be used after the application is up and running. Liquibase is a tool for managing schema change, not something that should be used for controlling application data.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same issue with Liquibase in docker-compose by passing variables as environment arguments:
docker-compose.yaml

```
  liquibase:
    container_name: liquibase
    image: liquibase/liquibase
    command: liquibase --url="jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres" --changeLogFile=changelog.xml --username=${USR} --password=${PSW} update
    volumes:
      - ./backend-liquibase/changelog.xml:/liquibase/changelog.xml
      - ./backend-liquibase/scripts:/liquibase/scripts
    environment:
      - BU=${POSTGRES_BACKEND_USER}
      - BP=${POSTGRES_BACKEND_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

changelog.xml

```
<databaseChangeLog  
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">  
    <includeAll  path="/scripts/"/>
    
    <changeSet id="init-db-001" author="ha">
        <comment>Init users and schema</comment>
        <sql>
            CREATE USER ${BU} WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD '${BP}';
        </sql>
        <rollback>
            <sql>
                
            </sql>
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```